# int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter or int-aws:s3-outbound-gateway is not throwing any error when there is no access permission at bucket level

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

I am facing one issue in both int-aws:s3-outbound-gateway and int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter . The issue is, Suppose if i don't have the bucket access permission which is already configured as a destination bucket the adapter should throw run time error in the console but I am not getting any error in the console and files are not moved to the respective destination.
Could you please advice on this

```
     <int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter 
        id="moverId"
        channel="ChannelGateway" 
        transfer-manager="tf"
        bucket-expression="bucketName"
        key-expression="headers.file_name"
        command="UPLOAD">
    <int-aws:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="retryAdvice" />
    </int-aws:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-aws:s3-outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get any errors because such an upload is an *async* operation.

The `S3MessageHandler` is fully based on the AWS S3 `TransferManager`. And when we upload the file into the remote bucket it is done by this operation:

```
/**
 * <p>
 * Schedules a new transfer to upload data to Amazon S3. This method is
 * non-blocking and returns immediately (i.e. before the upload has
 * finished).
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * Use the returned <code>Upload</code> object to query the progress of the
 * transfer, add listeners for progress events, and wait for the upload to
 * complete.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * If resources are available, the upload will begin immediately. Otherwise,
 * the upload is scheduled and started as soon as resources become
 * available.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * If you are uploading <a href="http://aws.amazon.com/kms/">AWS
 * KMS</a>-encrypted objects, you need to specify the correct region of the
 * bucket on your client and configure AWS Signature Version 4 for added
 * security. For more information on how to do this, see
 * http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html#
 * specify-signature-version
 * </p>
 *
 * @param putObjectRequest
 *            The request containing all the parameters for the upload.
 * @param progressListener
 *            An optional callback listener to receive the progress of the
 *            upload.
 *
 * @return A new <code>Upload</code> object to use to check the state of the
 *         upload, listen for progress notifications, and otherwise manage
 *         the upload.
 *
 * @throws AmazonClientException
 *             If any errors are encountered in the client while making the
 *             request or handling the response.
 * @throws AmazonServiceException
 *             If any errors occurred in Amazon S3 while processing the
 *             request.
 */
public Upload upload(final PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest,
        final S3ProgressListener progressListener)
```

Pay attention to the second argument if this method: the `S3MessageHandler` provides such a hook for your use case:

```
/**
 * Specify a {@link S3ProgressListener} for upload and download operations.
 * @param s3ProgressListener the {@link S3ProgressListener} to use.
 * @see MessageS3ProgressListener
 */
public void setProgressListener(S3ProgressListener s3ProgressListener) {
```

And you need to track there a `progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent)` for an appropriate `ProgressEventType`.